# Converting from server image URL to absolute address

Tags: php

I guess this is a simple question but I really can't find anything that would help me.

I'm using an image download script and for that I need an image URL that looks like:
"/home/clients/websites/w_apo/public_html/apo/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/Beautiful.jpg"
[type1]

but what I have is:
"http://www.apo.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/Beautiful.jpg"
[type2]

I tried to write a function that returns the URL of type 1 to the URL of type 2 but it doesn't work all that great.
This is how it looks:

```
function relativeToServerAddress($relativeURL) {
    $paths = explode('wp-content/', $relativeURL);
    $thePath = getcwd()."/wp-content"."/".$paths[1];
    return $thePath;
}
```

Is there any better way to do this? I tried to find a predefined function but failed.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
$file = basename("http://www.apo.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/Beautiful.jpg");
return getcwd()."/wp-content/".$file;
```

?
you need to inform us with the directories you wish to keep/move from absolute url;
the above just copies the file.